# MVVM localization in the business logic

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, localization

I am refactoring an existing WinForms application into WPF and MVVM (little knowledge apart from theory in MVVM). The application needs to be fully localized. I am OK with this as far as the UI goes (store resources and bind to them based off enumerations and other structures).

The application must present a dynamically generated pdf to the user. Where should this localization information go:

1. In the backend with the pdf creation logic

   Pro: easier logic flow

   Con: against MVVM theory, as backend is not supposed to know anything about how it is being displayed. Also less maintainable (2 places with localization data)
2. Pass the objects to the view to translate. This will mean PDF generation code would need to come into the view.

   Pro: Only one spot to maintain localization

   Con: Also against MVVM theory, as view is not supposed to have logic in it

Neither solution really seems ideal to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite not understandable but practical solution to localization is :

1.Create project with .resx files (project name can be e.g. Localization)

2.Add namespace to your XAML file e.g.

```
xmlns:localPresentation="clr-namespace:Localization.Presentation;assembly=Localization"
```

3.Localize UI text in this way

```
Text="{x:Static localPresentation:PresentationResources.SomeResourceKey}"
```

This localization is not dynamic. When you change language of the application, you have to restart it. Dynamic localization is more tricky but everything is possible.

Comment: My question is not about localising the UI. My question is about localising files generated in the backend. If I have to present a translated .pdf file to the user, do I pass the objects up to the view to translate, and then back to the view model to make the pdf? Or do I store translation info in the backend with the pdf logic?

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make it easier for you to understand me.

Comment: You're right. I didn't understand question correctly. From my point of view you have to do it in backend. It is not nice solution to pass data to UI for translation, it doesn't have sense. But maybe I still don't understand where do you have problem. If you set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture it should work.

Answer (score 1):

These details might help for Globalization and Localization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753931.aspx)

and there is also a guidance on codeplex:WPF Localization Guidance  (http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/releases/view/29389)

Comment: Thanks for the links, unfortunately neither seemed to have anything relating to my situation of translating a dynamically generated data file for the user.